# Copyfiles from Directory Tree to Flat Folder - Keep most Recent

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, backup

I am trying to create a batch file that will allow me to copy files that are scattered across several directories into a single location while maintaining the most recent copy available.
This is for a Windows machine.

For example...

```
C:\Base Files\*.jpg
C:\Base Files\Sub\*.jpg
C:\Base Files\Sub2\*.jpg
```

and copy all of these to `C:\Backup`.

I am trying to do something like the following...

```
FORFILES /p "C:\Base Files\DIR01\My Images" /s /M *.JPG /c "copy @file C:\SANDBOX\DIR02"
```

But it dumps out each time right away with a "File not found" message.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if we change "maintaining the most recent copy" by "copying only the modified files", then this command do that:

```
xcopy "C:\Base Files\*.*" C:\Backup /m /s
```

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
forfiles /s /p "C:\SourceFolder" /C "cmd /c copy @path C:\DestinationFolder"
```